# If subgroups are preserved under preimages, is it necessarily a homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

Consider a function $f : G \rightarrow H$, where $G$ and $H$ are groups, such that preimage of every subgroup of $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Is it possible that $f$ could fail to be a homomorphism? Is it possible that $f$ could be surjective, yet fail to be a homomorphism?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a cyclic group of order $p$ with prime $p>3$, and let $f$ fix the identity and permute the non-identity elements. Not all such maps are homomorphisms. There are only two subgroups, so the inverse image condition is satisfied.

Comment: Good reflexes. Do you know of any interesting ways of strengthening the conditions so that no such $f$ can fail to be a homomorphism?

Comment: @goblin: If you look just at subgroups not elements, you cannot distinguish the generators of cyclic subgroups.